# Handling Timeout Error for queue jobs in production

Tags: php, linux, laravel

I am created Laravel Jobs for importing data which includes calculation. Im already using **supervisor** for queues. Everything works fine for 100 - 300 data, but I'm receiving a timeout error if exceeds that limit.

How can I set the timeout to **0** to finish the job. I've tried to include `public $timeout = 0;` in my Jobs class including **supervisor** configuration but no luck. Im still receiving a timeout error.

Please help I've been stuck here for days.

Answer (score 1):

in your laravel-worker.conf , use --timout=0.0 instead of 0

```
command=php /mnt/c/laravel/octane/artisan queue:listen --timeout=0.0
```